# how to make a correct HTTP request to BigQuery from google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery, authorization, urlfetch

I am working in google script API trying to get a schema of a table from BiqQuery... not sure why it is so troublesome.

I am sending a request like this :

```
let url =  'https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/'+ projectId +'/datasets/'+ datasetId +'/tables/' +tableId; 

 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)
```

I am getting this response:

> Exception: Request failed for https://bigquery.googleapis.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: { "error": { "code": 401, "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie ... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 68, file "bigQuery")

I have been able to load data to bigQuery alright... not sure why this does not work. I have looked at the OAuth fields in manifest and the script does have access to bigQuery...

no success also when adding this to the options field of the UrlFetch request

```
var authHeader = 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD);
    var options = {
      headers: {Authorization: authHeader}
    }
```

Comment: Basic authentication does not contain OAuth scopes info, try with bearer token. 1. get token via `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()` and send it as `Bearer <token here>`.

Comment: @Oleg Valter - thank you! it worked - perfect.  What is the reason that my other functions addressing bigQuery work and this HTTP request needed this extra token?  I thus successfully got the table schema from BigQuery.  Is this the cleanest way to achieve that?

Comment: makmak, well, for Google Apps Script environment, there is an Advanced Service that wraps around the BigQuery REST API specifically for GAS: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery, so you don't have to worry about such things as auth or parsing the response. I personally don't like advanced services too much, but they act as sort of useful libraries. 
P.s. Glad you I could help

Comment: As for the other calls to the API - I am not sure, my best guess is that they do not require authentication. If you provide more info about the endpoints which allowed you to request them without the bearer token, I can say for sure and / or test

Comment: @Oleg Valter I have been able to load  BigQuery.Jobs.insert(loadJob, projectId, blob);  And I suppose all proper API calls will work as well.  For finding the table schema though I could not find anything except the HTTP request. Or a "bq show" call for command prompt (which supposedly just makes a REST Api request though I could not reconstruct one)

Comment: makmak, I mean when trying to connect to the API directly - if you used the advanced service from the start, then it is expected that when you tried to connect via REST API call, you were rejected because only the advanced service does the auth for you. As for the definitions - what is correct for the API is also correct for the advanced service. For example, tables `insert` : `BigQuery.Tables.insert(table, projectId, datasetId)`

Comment: A small suggestion - if you use a local IDE, install [@types/google-apps-script](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google-apps-script) module, it contains all the necessary definitions for both built-in services and advanced ones (look for `Bigquery` definition) - I find it very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use bearer tokens**

The reason why the BigQuery API rejects your requests is that the endpoint requires one of the following scopes to be provided with the access token to work, and it is missing from the request:

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery 
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform 
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery.readonly 
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only

The actual issue here is that the basic authorization scheme lacks info about any claims, only sending over correct credentials. Since you are requesting the endpoint directly with `UrlFetch` service, despite correctly specifying the scopes in the manifest, they will not be sent over.

[`ScriptApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app) service now provides an easy method to get a valid bearer token without using an OAuth 2.0 library or building the flow from scratch: [`getOAuthToken`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getoauthtoken). Pass it to an `Authorization` header as bearer token, and you should be all set:

```
const token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

const options = {
  headers : {
    Authorization : `Bearer ${token}`
  }
};
```

---

**Use Advanced Service**

As an alternative, there is an official [advanced service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery) as a wrapper around BigQuery REST API that will manage authentication and response parsing for you.

> You must [enable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) the BigQuery advanced service before using it

Also, note that the advanced service identifier is configurable, so you have to reference the identifier you chose.

In your case, the service can be used as follows (assuming you used the default `BigQuery` identifier). There is also the 4th argument of type `object` that contains optional arguments (not shown here):

```
Bigquery.Tables.get("projectId","datasetId", "tableId");
```

The method chain above corresponds to [`tables.get`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/get) method of the BigQuery API.

Comment: I guess I was a bit blurry on the difference between the REST API and the Advanced Service. Still bit blurry-   I was definitely on the [page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/get) of the tables.get method many times while trying to solve this.  Is there similar documentation for the advanced service?  Which is clearly what I want to be using  (the call you suggested worked).  I understand that the script module (your last comment on the question) kind of helps to navigate thru while coding. (I am in the google editor so it is there by default).

Comment: @makmak - unfortunately, for every advanced service, Google points to the REST API does, so I don't think there is any documentation on the service (there might be unofficial ones, but I don't know of any). The closest you can get is literally inspecting the `ts` file or making a JSDoc of your own, but that is not worth the effort...